# How to return NULL object in C++

Tags: c++

I know that this might be a duplicate of: [Return a "NULL" object if search result not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639255/c-return-a-null-object-if-search-result-not-found)

BUT, there's something different going on with my code because the asterisk doesn't solve my problem, which is this:

```
Normal Sphere::hit(Ray ray) {
   //stuff is done here
   if(something happens) {
       return NULL;
   }
   //other stuff
   return Normal(something, somethingElse);
}
```

But I get an error referencing the `return NULL` line: `conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘Normal’ requested`

And another error and warning that referencing the last return line: `warning: taking address of temporary` and `conversion from ‘Normal*’ to non-scalar type 'Normal' requested`

I understand why I am getting this warning, but I don't know how to fix it. How do I return a `Normal` object in the last line that persists after the function ends and how do I return a `NULL` object that first time? (If there's a term for these types of returns, please let me know so I can also read up on it more.)

To clarify a commenter's question, I've tried these things:

I tried doing this: `Normal *Sphere::hit(Ray ray)` in the cpp file and `Normal *hit( Ray ray );` in the header file and I get this error: `error: prototype for ‘Normal* Sphere::hit(Ray)’ does not match any in class 'Sphere'`

I also tried this: `Normal Sphere::*hit(Ray ray)` in the cpp file and `Normal *hit( Ray ray);` in the header file and I get this error for the second return statement: `cannot convert 'Normal*' to 'Normal Sphere::*' in return`

**Further clarification:** I'm not asking about how pointers work. (That wasn't the main question.) I'm wondering about syntax regarding pointers in C++. So, given the function I've specified above, I've gleaned that I should specify a return a pointer because C++ doesn't have null objects. Got it. BUT, the problem then becomes: what should the function prototype look like? In the cpp file, I have what Bala suggested (which is what I had originally but changed it because of the following error):

```
Normal* Sphere::hit(Ray ray) {
   //stuff is done here
   if(something happens) {
       return NULL;
   }
   //other stuff
   return new Normal(something, somethingElse);
}
```

In the header file, I have `Normal *hit(Ray ray)`, but I still get this message: `prototype for 'Normal* Sphere::hit(Ray)' does not match any in class 'Sphere'` At this point, it is unclear to me why it can't find that function prototype. Here is the header file:

```
class Sphere
{
    public:
        Sphere();
        Vector3 center;
        float radius;
        Normal* hit(Ray ray);
};
```

Can anyone see why it's complaining that there doesn't exist a matching prototype for `hit` in the `Sphere` class? (I might move this to a separate question...)

Comment: "The astrisk" makes the return statement a return of a pointer, you can have null pointers, you can't have null constant objects.

Comment: This question makes it clear that you need to read up on what a pointer is and how you use it. This is a non-trivial subject: not actually *hard* but picky and easy to get wrong.

Comment: You might want to consider boost::optional http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you need something like

```
Normal* Sphere::hit(Ray ray) {
   //stuff is done here
   if(something happens) {
       return NULL;
   }
   //other stuff
   return new Normal(something, somethingElse);
}
```

to be able to return NULL;

Comment: What would the prototype look like? I have `Normal* hit( Ray ray );` but it's not matching properly and g++ says this: `prototype for 'Normal* Sphere::hit(Ray)' does not match any in class 'Sphere'`

Comment: @Bala - while this is the correct answer in regard to returning `null`, the OP obviously doesn't understand the difference between returning a copy of an object vs. a pointer to one given his question; an explanation of the difference would be beneficial.

Comment: @Jackie that prototype looks fine to me and seems to compile fine http://ideone.com/4nbwB

Comment: @Brian my bad! Now that there is so much explanation, I'll just delete my answer.

Comment: @Bala, I like you answer the most because that's what I had originally (before even what I listed in my original draft of the question), but g++ continues to complain that there is no matching prototype. I must be missing something here... I've updated the question to detail my further complications. If you have any insight as to why g++ might be throwing that error, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: This is a good recipe for memory leaks. `new` and raw pointers and no ownership semantics, oh my.

Comment: to be fair, `std::unique_ptr` didn't really exist yet when this was written.

Answer (score 29):

There are several fairly standard ways of doing this. There are different tradeoffs for the methods, which I'm not going to go into here.

Method 1: Throw an exception on failure.

```
Normal Sphere::hit(Ray ray)
{
   //stuff is done here
   if(something happens) {
       throw InvalidIntersection;
   }
   //other stuff
   return Normal(something, somethingElse);
}

void example(Ray r)
{
   try {
     Normal n = s.hit(r);
     ... SUCCESS CASE ...
   }
   catch( InvalidIntersection& )
   {
      ... FAILURE CASE ...
   }
}
```

Method 2 return a pointer to a newly allocated object. (You could also use smart pointers, or auto_ptrs to make this a little neater).

```
Normal* Sphere::hit(Ray ray)
{
   //stuff is done here
   if(something happens) {
       return NULL
   }
   //other stuff
   return new Normal(something, somethingElse);
}

void example(Ray ray)
{
  Normal * n = s.hit(ray);
  if(!n) {
     ... FAILURE CASE ...
  } else {
    ... SUCCESS CASE ...
    delete n;
  }
}
```

Method 3 is to update an existing object. (You could pass a reference, but a convention I use is that any output parameter is passed by pointer).

```
bool Sphere::hit(Ray ray, Normal* n)
{
   //stuff is done here
   if(something happens) {
       return false
   }
   //other stuff
   if(n) *n = Normal(something, somethingElse);
   return true;
}

void example(Ray ray)
{
  Normal n;
  if( s.hit(ray, &n) ) {
     ... SUCCESS CASE ...
  } else {
     ... FAILURE CASE ...
  }
}
```

Method 4: Return an `optional<Normal>` (using boost or similar)

```
optional<Normal> Sphere::hit(Ray ray)
{
   //stuff is done here
   if(something happens) {
       return optional<Normal>();
   }
   //other stuff
   return optional<Normal>(Normal(something, somethingElse));
}

void example(Ray ray)
{
  optional<Normal> n = s.hit(ray);
  if( n ) {
     ... SUCCESS CASE (use *n)...
  } else {
     ... FAILURE CASE ...
  }
}
```

Comment: There's another option `Normal(smt something, smt somethingElse){  this->something = something;  this->somethingElse = somethingElse;   this->has_value = true;  }

                RegionDefinition()  {   this->has_value = false;  }

                smt something;
                smt somethingElse;
                bool has_value;` ;)

Answer (score 10):

If you use the Boost libraries, then you can use boost::optional. That gives you something that is pretty close to a null value:

```
boost::optional<Normal> Sphere::hit(Ray ray) {
   //stuff is done here
   if(something happens) {
       return boost::none;
   }
   //other stuff
   return Normal(something, somethingElse);
}
```

boost::optional< T> is a wrapper class that contains either an instance of T or boost::none (an instance of boost::none_t).

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html for more details.

Comment: You should mention how to test and extract the value from a boost::optional object.

Answer (score 5):

In C++ there's no such thing as a "null object".  There are null pointers though.  You can implement a special object of your design that you logically treat as "null" but it's not part of the C++ language.

Answer (score 1):

The NULL return value would only be valid if you were returning a pointer to a Normal object, NULL represents a null pointer, not a null object.

What I would do in this case is define a 'null' or invalid state for this object. Since you are working with surface normals, you can consider a normal with length == 0 an invalid state, so then you would do this:

```
Normal Sphere::hit(Ray ray) {
   //stuff is done here
   if(something happens) {
       return Normal();
   }
   //other stuff
   return Normal(something, somethingElse);
}
```

Then your normal class would have something like this:

```
class Normal {
public:
    Normal() : x(0), y(0), z(0), len(0) {}
    // ... other constructors here ...

    bool isValid() const { return (len != 0) };

    // ... other methods here ...

private:
    float x, y, z, len;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> BUT, there's something different going on with my code because the
> asterisk doesn't solve my problem, which is this:

It seems that from your question you expect that simply adding a `*` after the class name will solve your problems. However this sort of expectation comes from a lack of understanding what a pointer is, when to use pointers and the importance of the type system. So the remainder of this answer will hopefully clarify these points.

Firstly the C++ is a strongly typed lanuage. This means that when assigning one variable to another that 2 variables in question have to be of the same type. For example assume that in the code below A and B are basic classes with no members defined:

```
A a;
B b;
a = b; //compiler error here due to type mismatch
```

This is because `a` and `b` are different types.

Now say you created a pointer by using the `*`. This is also a different type of variable:

```
A a;
A* p_a;
a = p_a; //compiler error due to type mismatch
```

`p_a` is not the same type of variable as `a`.

Now the error:

> conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘Normal’ requested

is generated because the expression:

```
return NULL
```

is of type `int` (you'll find if you look it up it's #defined as 0) but the return type of your function is `Normal`.

To resolve this you have to change the function return type to be a `pointer to a Normal` object.

```
Normal* Sphere::hit(Ray ray)
```

and return a `pointer to a Normal` object:

```
return new Normal(something, somethingElse);
```

However at this stage although compiler errors should be resolved, you now have the concern of managing the dynamically allocated memory. I can't cover that in this post so I'll leave it like it is.

### Update:

This is to address the 2nd part in your question. Your class declaration in your header file should be terminated with a `;`.

Comment: thanks for the update. Unfortunately, it was my fault for not copying my code over properly. The class declaration does indeed end with a semicolon. And I do indeed still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't return `NULL`, which is a zero constant of type `int`, but instead, return an empty instance of class `Normal` constructed by the no arg constructor, usually.

So return `Normal();`

Generally, it is good practice to additionally have the method `isEmpty()` defined.

That way you could check for a `Null` instance like so:

```
if(obj_of_class_Normal.isEmpty())
       //do something.
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to face this type of problem. If you want to, for the unqualified conditon, you can just return the `normal` object with the lowest/ default value you want, like example:

```
Normal Sphere::hit(Ray ray) {
   //stuff is done here
   if(something happens) {
       return Normal(0,0); //here I take the example by constructing the 'normal' object with all value zeros
   }
   //other stuff
   return Normal(something, somethingElse);
}
```

Since the return type of your function is `Normal`, you can just pass an object of type `Normal` with lowest value, like example zero or something, then you can handle further when the stack of the function terminated.

Hope this solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (C++17)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional> // std::optional
#include <string>
 
// optional can be used as the return type of a factory that may fail
std::optional<std::string> create(bool b)
{
    if (b)
        return "Godzilla";
    return {};
}
 
// std::nullopt can be used to create any (empty) std::optional
auto create2(bool b)
{
    return b ? std::optional<std::string>{"Godzilla"} : std::nullopt;
}
 
int main()
{
    std::cout << "create(false) returned "
              << create(false).value_or("empty") << '\n';
 
    // optional-returning factory functions are usable as conditions of while and if
    if (auto str = create2(true))
        std::cout << "create2(true) returned " << *str << '\n';
}
```