# How to return a reference to an object that is inside a vector of smart pointers

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I have a `vector` of smart pointers to an `Image` `class`, like this:

```
class Controller
{
    //...
    typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Image>> ImageVector;
    ImageVector mImageVector;
}
```

And I have method that must return a reference to the `Image`, like this:

```
Image& Controller::getImage(const std::string name)
{
    for (auto& image : mImageVector) 
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Image> p = image;
        if(p->getName() == name) //find the correct pointer to image in the vector
            return p.get; // returns a reference to a image <---ERROR!! What should be here?
    }
}
```

**How can I return a reference to an object, that it is inside a vector of shared_ptr to those objects?**

Basically my idea is to make a method that search the vector that has the same string (in the object) as the method parameter. If find, then returns a reference to that object (not to the shared_ptr, but to the object itself).

Comment: Do it like you would if the shared_ptr was not inside of a vector.

Comment: For that you need a mutable empty image, if the image can not be found - no good !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
for (auto& image : mImageVector)
```

`image` is a reference to the std::shared_ptr in `mImageVector`.  To return a reference to the `Image` just dereference it.

```
Image& Controller::getImage(const std::string name)
{
    for (auto& image : mImageVector) 
    {
        if(image->getName() == name) //find the correct pointer to image in the vector
            return *image; //return the Image
    }
}
```

If you ever have to deal with an element not being present in the list then you can return a shared pointer/pointer instead of a reference and set that pointer to null if the item does not exist.

Comment: And if a suitable image isn't found?

Answer (score 2):

To get the regular pointer to the object, use `(p.get())` not `p.get`. Then, to get a reference to the pointed object, dereference the pointer:

```
return *(p.get());
```

As commented on NathanOliver post, your code does not handle the case where no suitable image could be found. So it would be recommended to return a pointer (`Image*` using `p.get()`) so that `NULL` can be returned if no image was found (or you may also return a reference to a local `static` empty `Image`, it's an alternative). But that is actuallyanother SO question: [Return a "NULL" object if search result not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639255/c-return-a-null-object-if-search-result-not-found)